# How javascript prototype and jquery extend are different

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, extends

I am confused over [**javascript prototype**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp) and [**jquery extend**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). I referred to their respective tutorial pages but ended up with confusion. Please have a look at below example which almost resembles with a 100 lines of code I have in my project.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnClik").click(
        function () {
             this.to = new TestObj('hello');
            this.to.alertFun();
            this.to.alertFun2('from alertFun2');
        }            
    );
});

var TestObj = (function () {
    function TestObj(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

$.extend(TestObj.prototype, {
    alertFun: function () {
        alert(this.msg);
    },

    alertFun2: function(mesge){
        alert(mesge);
    }
});
return TestObj;
})();
```

Here is the [filddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Metri/82d8k/)
If javascript prototype extends properties then what is the need of using jquery extend? It would be helpful if you could explain with respect to my example above.
**Edit**
What does this line do `$.extend(TestObj.prototype, {some functions} - please refer above code'`.

Comment: "How javascript prototype and jquery extend are different" --- they are **completely different**. What makes you thinking they are even comparable?

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking about. `$.extend()` is a helper function that copies object properties from one to another. Of course you can do the same with prototype, but writing `$.extend( a, b );` is much easier than several lines of code traversing through the properties of the second object and inserting them into `a`.

Comment: @zerkms. If that is the case, can you explain what does this line do `'$.extend(TestObj.prototype, {'`. Thanks

Comment: The line you ask about extends the `TestObj`'s prototype with the functions, as you well know.

Comment: @Metri: have you tried to read the corresponding documentation page?

Comment: Here is the [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbSSvTTBc6E) for Javascript OOP tutorial which covers prototype. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.extend` simply adds all of the key/value pairs from one object to another.  It has many uses.

Its use when adding to `MyObject.prototype` is therefore just a shorthand method of adding multiple properties to the `.prototype` all in one go.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak for your effort to explain.